# ¿Cómo funciona exactamente nth-child?

Tags: html, css

La pseudoclase `:nth-child` se suele usar en tablas o listados para diferenciar las filas pares de las impares:

```css
li:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>elemento1</li>
  <li>elemento2</li>
  <li>elemento3</li>
  <li>elemento4</li>
</ul>
```

O para seleccionar un elemento hijo concreto:

```css
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>elemento1</li>
  <li>elemento2</li>
  <li>elemento3</li>
  <li>elemento4</li>
</ul>
```

Sin embargo tiene una sintaxis más compleja, he visto casos de este estilo:

```
p:nth-child(4n+2)
```

No acabo de comprender muy bien que hace exactamente y qué usos prácticos puede tener.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

La pseudoclase `:nth-child()` selecciona los hermanos que cumplan cierta condición definida en la fórmula `an + b`. `a` y `b` deben ser números enteros, `n` es un contador. El grupo `an` representa un ciclo, cada cuantos elementos se repite; `b` indica desde donde empezamos a contar.

Vamos a verlo con ejemplos para entenderlo mejor:

**Seleccionar cada tres elementos empezando por el segundo:**

```
:nth-child(3n + 2)
```

```css
#contenedor :nth-child(3n + 2){
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar cada tres elementos:**

```
:nth-child(3n + 0)
```

Cuando `b=0` se puede omitir quedando:

```
:nth-child(3n)
```

```css
#contenedor :nth-child(3n){
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar el segundo elemento:**

```
:nth-child(0n + 2)
```

Cuando `a=0` se puede omitir `an` y nos queda:

```
:nth-child(2)
```

```css
#contenedor :nth-child(2){
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar cada dos elementos hasta el sexto:**

También podemos usar números negativos. Cuando `a` es negativo solo se repite el ciclo hasta `b`:

```
:nth-child(-2n + 6)
```

```css
#contenedor :nth-child(-2n + 6){
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar todos los elementos hasta el sexto:**

si `a=1` o `a=-1` podemos omitir `a`:

```
:nth-child(-n + 6)
```

```css
#contenedor :nth-child(-n + 6){
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar el primer elemento:**

Si lo que quisiéramos fuera seleccionar el primer elemento podemos utilizar la pseudoclase `first-child`, una pseudoclase específica para este propósito.

Equivaldría a utilizar cualquiera de las siguientes pseudoclases:

- `nth-child(0n+1)`
- `nth-child(1)`

```css
#contenedor p:first-child{
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar el último elemento:**

De igual manera, también podemos seleccionar el último elemento mediante la pseudoclase `last-child`:

```css
#contenedor p:last-child{
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Palabras clave:**

Para seleccionar elementos pares e impares también tenemos las palabras clave `odd` y `even`:

```
:nth-child(odd)
:nth-child(even)
```

```css
#contenedor :nth-child(odd){
  border:solid 1px red;
}
   #contenedor :nth-child(even){
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <p>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</p>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <p>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</p>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <p>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</p>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Seleccionar el enésimo elemento de un tipo concreto:**

A veces ocurre que queremos seleccionar, por ejemplo, el segundo párrafo hijo de un `div` que tiene varios elementos-hijo distintos e intentamos algo así:

```
p:nth-child(2)
```

```css
#contenedor p:nth-child(2) {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, libero!</p>
  <div>Nulla temporibus ipsa consequatur, cumque non error mollitia officiis nostrum.</div>
  <p>Nihil magnam alias non quos maxime animi, sequi nisi ratione!</p>
  <p>Distinctio sunt, dolorum id at soluta quas, quisquam et delectus.</p>
  <div>Sit totam sint quibusdam cum hic, non aliquid praesentium vero.</div>
  <p>Iure, ex mollitia nesciunt doloribus minima maxime libero amet doloremque?</p>
  <div>Laborum sed facere magni blanditiis sit id vel enim voluptas.</div>
  <p>Quo, cupiditate debitis voluptates quae vel, saepe sint adipisci qui!</p>
  <p>Perspiciatis sed inventore ipsa facilis deleniti corporis beatae, ipsum libero.</p>
  <p>Minima est dolore quia quae laudantium magnam dolorem modi ullam.</p>
</div>
```

No funciona porque `p:nth-child(2)` busca el segundo hijo que además sea un `p` y como el segundo hijo no es un `p` no se cumple la condición y no hace nada.

¿Se podría hacer eso de alguna forma? Sí, pero con otra pseudoclase llamada `:nth-of-type()` que funciona básicamente igual pero solo cuenta los elementos del tipo elegido.

Comment: Qué bien que la pusieras en modo wiki de comunidad. Sin embargo, parece que fuiste el único editor, por lo que podrías haber mantenido la propiedad

Comment: Creo que solo le faltaría `nth-first-child` y `nth-last-child` para completar la respuesta. Por lo demás, muy completa.

Comment: @blonfu Dicho y hecho, ya están ambas pseudoclases añadidas ;)

Comment: @FranciscoRomero perfecto! Así está mejor