# ¿Aplicar estilos CSS a elementos a partir de 1 + n?

Tags: html, css

no maqueto mucho y me he encontrado con cierta situación.

Tengo una serie de párrafos dentro un div. Quisiera **aplicar un estilo CSS a todos los párrafos a partir de una posición determinada**, por ejemplo, a partir del tercer párrafo el resto no aparecerán, es decir que el siguiente código:

```
<div class="prueba">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

muestre sólo:

```
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
```

***Nota:*** el número de párrafos es indeterminado, por eso no puedo hacer algo como:

```
p:nth-of-type(4),
p:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo funciona exactamente nth-child?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/90648/7176). Es `nth-child` no  `nth-of-type` pero la sintaxis es la misma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu elemento a partir del que deseas aplicar algo sea el cuarto, debes usar el pseudo selector `:nth-of-type` mandandole una fórmula.

Las fórmulas se hacen de la siguiente manera:

```
an+b
```

Donde vada uno de los elementos significa:

- `n` es nuestra variable, si no ponemos nada lo aplicará a todos
- `a` es el cuantificador de múltiplos si ponemos por ejemplo 2n lo aplicará cada que n sea divisible exactamente entre 2
- `b` es nuestro desfase. Es decir a partir de este número de elementos se empieza a aplicar el resto de la fórmula.

```css
p:nth-of-type(n+4) {
  /* display: none;*/
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="prueba">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una ***posible solución combinando selectores CSS***:

```
.prueba p:nth-of-type(3) ~ p {
    display: none;
}
```

Primero selecciono el elemento precedente a los que llevarán el estilo, en este caso el tercer párrafo, que será el último visible dentro del div. A partir de este elemento usó el selector ~ para seleccionar el resto de elementos de tipo párrafo que restan.